# Python Login into an website with requests

Tags: python, forms, post, authentication, python-requests

Im tryin to login into this page with python and requests via post methode:
http://pastebin.com/eD9Wc4TS
*(the javascript in script.js: http://pastebin.com/Cd2DRrEn)*

Here's what I tried:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'page':'','pass':'4376','ID':'2'} #login data
print payload
link    = 'http://abi16.rsgohlis.de/login.php'
session = requests.Session() #session

resp    = session.post(link,headers = headers,data = payload) #forgot payload
resp = session.get('http://abi16.rsgohlis.de/home.php')

print resp.content
```

But everytime I try it leads me back to the starting page saying that I'm not logged in(although using the right combination). It'd be enough for me if the website would response with

> Das Passwort ist leider falsch.

*(which is german for **wrong password**)*

But it only responds by stating

> Du musst angemeldet sein, um diese Seite sehen zu können.

*(which is german again for **you must be logged in to see this page**)*

My question is, how to keep up the session to really login and at least get the login error?

**Edit:** As @juvian pointed out, I forgot to add the payload. However, nothing changed in the end unfortunately.

Comment: You are not doing anything with payload in your code

Comment: @juvian thanks for pointing it out. However, I'm still getting the same result unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly using the form names of login and pass? They change on every page

Comment: Yes everything is correct. I took them directly from http://abi16.rsgohlis.de/

Comment: Can only guess that user/pass is wrong then, as the code seems fine. Also, do the print resp.content after your post if you want to see the Das Passwort ist leider falsch.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also send other form data to the server, such as CSRF tokens. 
Please see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143054/1299446